# Se puede programar un metodo/funcion con parametros de clase de datos c#

Tags: c#, .net

Necesito crear una método/función que recorra un DataGridView y dependiendo unos flags que he activado en cada una de las filas (nuevo, editado, eliminado) y dependiendo del flag debo ejecutar una función de una clase...

Se puede hacer lo que sugiero...

**Método/Función a crear:**

```
puclic bool GrabaTabla(DataGridView dgv, object objInsertar, object objActualizar, object objEliminar )
{
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
  //
  TypeRowFlag flag = row.RowFlag;
  //
  if (flag == TypeRowFlag.New){<br/>
    if (!objInsertar()) {return false;}
  }
  if (flag == TypeRowFlag.Edited){
    if (!objActualizar()) {return false;}
  }
  if (flag == TypeRowFlag.Deleted){
    if (!objEliminar()) {return false;}
  }
}
return true;
}
```

**Así usaría la función:**

```
GrabaTabla(dgvDetalle, dbVac.PeriodoAnualInsertar(), dbVac.PeriodoAnualActualizar(), 
 dbVac.PeriodoAnualEliminar());
```

Comment: Ya lo intentaste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma como interpreto tu planteamiento es la siguiente:
Quieres crear un Método con las siguientes características:

- Tiene 4 parámetros:

  - El primero es un `DataGridView` que contiene los datos a procesar.
  - Los otros 3 parámetros son los métodos que se deben ejecutar según el valor de una propiedad llamada `RowFlag` que forma parte de cada fila en el `DataGridView`.
- Por cada fila del `DataGridView`, se evalúa el valor de la propiedad `RowFlag` e invoca al método correspondiente:

  - `RowFlag.New` invoca a `objInsertar()`
  - `RowFlag.Edited` invoca a `objActualizar()`
  - `RowFlag.Deleted` invoca a `objEliminar()`
- Si alguno de los métodos invocados devuelve `false`, no son procesadas las filas restantes y el método `GrabaTabla` finaliza la ejecución devolviendo `false`

Con base en la interpretación anterior, la respuesta corta a tu pregunta es **sí se puede**.

Al revisar el método `GrabaTabla`, se puede ver que los parámetros `objInsertar`, `objActualizar` y `objEliminar` son métodos que devuelven un booleano, por lo tanto la modificación que debes hacer es reemplazar en tipo de dato de estos tres parámetros de `object` a `Func<bool>`. [`Ver más acerca del delegado Func<TResult>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Func%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1)

Luego de hacerlo, la firma de tu método quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public bool GrabaTabla(DataGridView dgv, Func<bool> objInsertar, Func<bool> objActualizar, Func<bool> objEliminar )
{
    //...
    // El resto del método debería funcionar tal como está
}
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo... realizo los cambios, lo aplico en mi libreria y comento que tal fue...

Comment: Lo aplique quedo perfecto... gracias Pablo... ahí publique el resultado como una respuesta...

Answer (score 1):

Gracias Pablo quedo perfecto... una mas para mi libro... tengo un par de meses empezando a programar en .Net... iré aprendiendo mientras...

**Así lo aplico en el formulario:**

```
{
  //grabando el detalle
  return dbVac.PeriodoAnualGrabarDetalle(dgvDetalle);
}
```

**Así lo aplique en la librería:**

```
{
  //ejecutando.
  return sql.fGrabaTabla( dgv, PeriodoAnualInsertar, PeriodoAnualActualizar, PeriodoAnualEliminar );
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es el resultado...

Comment: ya lo hice... gracias... soy nuevo aquí...